# How to limit the number of users that can download my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I developed a Chrome extension, and I want to publish it privately.

Is it possible to set a download limit (number of user that can download)?

For example, I set a domain for an organization, how I set the number of allowed downloads?

Also, is it possible to know who is downloading my chrome extension?

Answer (score 4):

You can't set a limit on the number of downloads, but you can explicitly list accounts if you select ["publish to testers" option](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#publishing-to-test-accounts).

It can be a fixed list or a Google Group you manage.

So, you could set up a group and control membership yourself. That way you both limit and know who is downloading.

With any other publishing option it's impossible to my knowledge to either limit or track downloads using the Web Store only (since you mention a domain, this may be different for Google Apps domains, but I doubt it).

Alternatively, you could impose a limit/tracking in the extension itself, by requiring a sign-in in the extension (for example, with the [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity)). Note that:

1. it's probably going to be annoying for users,
2. once downloaded, a tech-savvy user can modify your extension to remove any such checks unless a big chunk of your logic is server-side.